# IntelliJ random visual guide at column 115

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have visual column guides set up at 80 and 120. I am getting the one at 80. But I am not getting one at 120, instead I have one at 115.

[image: Settings window showing column guides at 80, 120]

[image: Code editor view, showing cursor at 115 and the vertical column is there too.]

Even with Visual guides turned off I still see that one at 115.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that the parameter hints occupy a few characters, and these characters are not included in the character length control. Indeed, these characters are indeed not part of your code.
[image]